# Pivot table deptno on columns and count and salary on rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

Can anybody correct me how what I'm doing wrong pivoting the rows and columns?

```
--Trying to count no. of employees in each dept and pivoting it as deptno on columns and counts of no. of employees
-- rows

SELECT 10, 20, 30
FROM emp
PIVOT
(
count(deptno)
FOR empno IN ([10],[20],[30])
)
as pt

--Trying to sum of salary in each dept and pivoting it as deptno on columns and sum of salary of rows but same repeating nature
-- rows

SELECT 10, 20, 30
FROM emp
PIVOT
(
deptno(deptno)
FOR deptno IN ([10],[20],[30])
)
as pt
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and i think there is a type it should be `sum(deptNo)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (deptno INT)

INSERT INTO @temp (deptno)
VALUES (10),(20),(20), (40),(30)

SELECT [10], [20], [30]
FROM @temp
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(deptno)
    FOR deptno IN ([10], [20], [30])
) pt
```

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi, it's difficult to argue with you :). Initially the user had specified in the SELECT block not columns names, but numeric constant values. To make the example to work, the columns names just need to be quoted.